# process connecting to another process to gather profile information?

Tags: .net, profiling, process

Are there any built-in mechanisms in .Net that would allow us to write two programs, A and B.  A is a process with special hooks onto which B attaches itself.  This would allow B to gather whatever information those hooks provided.

In particular, it would be nice to be able to dial into another of our process and gather suchs metrics like how many times a function was called in the last X minutes,  the average run length, how many items are in this or that cache, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* write an application with the [.NET Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301725.aspx). Or, you *could* use logging, controlled by runtime options, config files, or registry settings for how verbose your logs will be. Or you *could* pay a lot of money for existing commercial profiling solutions.

You *could* also use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) instead of logging.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. A lot of the metrics you describe can be captured with a profiler from within your debugger (so you wouldn't need to write program B at all, or change program A in any way).

Or you could implement a messaging interface (e.g. using sockets) that allows program B to request information from program A. Program A could supply a background thread to provide this information so that it can answer whenever a request is made regardless of what other work it might be engaged in.